# How to Configure postgresql User with SSL connection only?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, psql

My steps I did (psql v. 9.3):

- create psql user with password
- give him access to relevant databases
- allow connection from the outside (psql conf)
- and put "hostssl all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust" in pg_hba.conf

Do I need to create a key now to be able to connect?

How can I test that key if it works?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html).

If you didn't do that already, you'll have to configure the PostgreSQL server for SSL: create `server.crt` and `server.key` in the PostgreSQL data directory, set `ssl = on` in `postgresql.conf` and restart the server.

You don't need a client certificate or key to connect to the server.

To test if your setup works, just connect with `psql`.

If SSL is used, it will look as follows:

```
$ psql -d test -h 127.0.0.1
psql (9.3.13)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

test=#
```

Comment: Worked smoothly. Im now connected with SSL connection.

What I now need is a cert authentication for the enduser. Shall I create a new question or can you help me here?

Comment: No need for a question (like with this question), just follow configure it as described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-CERT).

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the trust to md5  (**EXTREMELY IMPORTANT**)
2. try to connect over psql from another system using different ssl settings (see the psql man page for this).

If you want to require a cert, then there are additional steps to do, but that's not specified in your question.  And cert authentication is possible but an advanced topic.